# docker-compose permissions error? pm2.json not found

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a Profittrailer Docker container through Docker Compose.
I've tested the Docker image using `docker run` which launches the container just fine.
When using `docker-compose up` instead, PM2 (NodeJS process manager) fails to find the configuration file. I believe this happens because the container is unable to write to the shared volume.

Below is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:8-jdk-alpine

ARG PT_VERSION=2.5.32
ENV PT_VERSION ${PT_VERSION}

RUN mkdir -p /app/

# install tools
RUN apk update && apk add unzip curl

# install nodejs
RUN apk add --update nodejs npm
RUN npm install pm2@latest -g

# install profittrailer
RUN curl https://github.com/taniman/profit-trailer/releases/download/$PT_VERSION/ProfitTrailer-$PT_VERSION.zip -L -o /app/profittrailer.zip
RUN unzip /app/profittrailer.zip -d /app/ && mv /app/ProfitTrailer-$PT_VERSION /app/ProfitTrailer

WORKDIR /app/ProfitTrailer
RUN chmod +x ProfitTrailer.jar

VOLUME /app/ProfitTrailer

CMD pm2 start pm2-ProfitTrailer.json && pm2 log 0

EXPOSE 8081
```

And the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  profittrailer:
    container_name: profittrailer
    image: "doccie/profittrailer:latest"
    volumes:
      - /home/[user]/.profittrailer:/app/ProfitTrailer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

The output logged (inside the container) is:

```
profittrailer    | [PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
profittrailer    | [PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
profittrailer    | [PM2][ERROR] File pm2-ProfitTrailer.json not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by not sharing the entire `app` directory, but limiting it to the folders and files I needed for configuration editing and migration.

```
version: '3'
services:
  profittrailer:
    container_name: profittrailer
    image: "doccie/profittrailer:latest"
    volumes:
      - /home/[USERNAME]/.profittrailer/data:/app/ProfitTrailer/data
      - /home/[USERNAME]/.profittrailer/application.properties:/app/ProfitTrailer/application.properties
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

I needed to set up the `application.properties` file first, since otherwise, it would create the file as a folder instead.